# Basic number theory question - $ord_p(x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a nonzero integer $x$ and prime $p$, define $ord_p(x)$ to be the largest integer $a$ such that $p^a \mid x$. We let $ord_p(0) = \infty$.  I would like to show that 
$$ord_p(x + y) = \min\{ord_p(x), ord_p(y)\}$$

if $ord_p(y) \ne ord_p(x)$.  Can someone check my proof?

Suppose $ord_p(x) \ne ord_p(y)$.  Clearly, if $a = \min\{ord_p(x), ord_p(y)\}$, then $p^a \mid x$ and $p^a \mid y$, which implies $p^a \mid x + y$.  By contradiction, suppose $p^{a+1} \mid x + y$, and assume WLOG, that $a = ord_p(x) < ord_p(y)$.  Then $a + 1 \le ord_p(y)$, so $p^{a+1} \mid y$, which implies $p^{a+1} \mid  x + y - y = x$.

Comment: Did you make up the notation $ord_p(x)$?  Normally this is denoted $\nu_p(x)$.  It's called the $p$-adic valuation.

Comment: Also, have you correctly written what you want to prove?  Because you seem to be proving $\nu_p(x+y) = \min\{\nu_p(x), \nu_p(y)\}$, which is much more promising!

Comment: @TaraB Sorry, correction made.

Comment: Proof is good: I would prefer fewer symbols. We may assume that $a$, the order of $x$, is less than the order of $y$. So $p^{a+1}$ divides $y$. Clearly $p^a$ divides $x+y$. If $p^{a+1}$ divided $x+y$, it would divide $(x+y)-y$, impossible. Same proof, but no min stuff, clearer to follow what's going on.

Comment: @Tara: The notation $\operatorname{ord}_p(x)$ is (also) rather standard in undergraduate texts.  For instance I use it in my number theory text: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/4400FULL.pdf.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark:  Ah, okay.  Perhaps especially when defining it only for the integers rather than for the rationals?

Comment: @Tara: I extend the $\operatorname{ord}_p$ notation to rationals on p. 18 of my text.  I'm not sure what everyone else does, but I can say that I didn't make up the notation either...

Comment: Have you given any thought to what happens if $ord_p(y) = ord_p(x)$ ? (I noticed Hagen implies that in his answer.)

Answer (score 3):

That's absolutely fine.
I similar way would be to show $\operatorname{ord}_p(a\pm b)\ge \min\{\operatorname{ord}_p(a),\operatorname{ord}_p(b)\}$ and then let $a=x+y$, $b=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is generally fine.  The only thing is that you should explicitly deal with the case that at least one of $ord_p(x)$ or $ord_p(y)$ is $\infty$, since your argument doesn't technically cover that. 
Also, I don't like 'By contradiction'.  What is that supposed to mean?  Perhaps you mean something like 'assume for a contradiction'.